# Audio devices working but not showing up in the settings

Tags: release-juno, settings, sound

I'm wondering if I can get some guidance on how elementary manages audio devices -- especially how it detects them. Do you use Pulse or ALSA? Is there potentially a package missing?

In my situation, I'm seeing...

> No Output Device
>   There is no output device detected. You may want to add one to start listening to anything.

...in System Settings --> Sound. However, `aplay -l` shows two Intel HDA cards, and vlc is able to play directly to the audio devices, so I know for sure the hardware is not an issue.

#### Edit:

I ran `io.elementary.switchboard` from the terminal with `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG` set to all, and found a message like `pa_context_connect () failed: Connection refused`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue for me. The permissions in the home folder were very strange -- `root:root` and `777`. I changed them to the my user and `755` for directories, `644` for files, and all works now. If you're running into this and you don't have messed up permissions in your home folder, I recommend you check the solutions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error) for more information.

Comment: Permissions for what file(s)?

Comment: If I recall correctly it was the whole home directory.